# Задать CornerRadius как Attached Property для ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Я смог сделать `CornerRadius` как Attached property для `Button` и `TextBox` с помощью класса

```
public class CornerRadiusSetter
{
    public static CornerRadius GetCornerRadius(DependencyObject obj) => (CornerRadius)obj.GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);

    public static void SetCornerRadius(DependencyObject obj, CornerRadius value) => obj.SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(Border.CornerRadius), typeof(CornerRadius),
            typeof(CornerRadiusSetter), new UIPropertyMetadata(new CornerRadius(), CornerRadiusChangedCallback));

    public static void CornerRadiusChangedCallback(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;

        if (control == null) return;

        control.Loaded += Control_Loaded;
    }

    private static void Control_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;

        if (control == null || control.Template == null) return;

        control.ApplyTemplate();

        Border border = control.Template.FindName("border", control) as Border;

        if (border == null) return;

        border.CornerRadius = GetCornerRadius(control);
    }
}
```

Это позволяет задать произвольный `CornerRadius` в XAML:

```
<TextBox local:CornerRadiusSetter.CornerRadius="5" />

<Button local:CornerRadiusSetter.CornerRadius="15">Button</Button>
```

---

Как сделать чтобы этот класс срабатывал ещё и для `ComboBox`?

После `control.ApplyTemplate()` добавлял такой код

```
Control toggleButton = control.Template.FindName("toggleButton", control) as Control;

if (toggleButton != null)
    SetCornerRadius(toggleButton, GetCornerRadius(control));

Border dropDownBorder = control.Template.FindName("DropDownBorder", control) as Border;

if (dropDownBorder != null)
    dropDownBorder.CornerRadius = GetCornerRadius(control);
```

Но ничего не менялось.

Comment: Ого, это подход так себе, это не то место где надо использовать AP. Просто сделайте стили для контролов.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Это вы про `Button` и `TextBox` говорите? Или про `ComboBox` тоже?

Comment: Про все контролы. Ваша задача решается правкой шаблона, а не AP и поиском элемента в шаблоне. В ComboBox, кстати, нет бордера, ограничивающего контент, поэтому только править шаблон

Comment: @АндрейNOP Если вы говорите про все контролы, то очень любопытно, как вы создадите `Button`ы с разными радиусами? Будете на каждый контрол создавать стили размером с десятки строк?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Чего-то не вижу чем ваше решение лучше. Я просто правлю `Border` встроенного шаблона и делаю один раз. И почему это на другой ОС я могу увидеть то, что не ожидал?

Comment: Не внимательно прочитал первый раз комментарий: В этом случае можно использовать AP, но только совместно со стилем, т. е. внутри стиля привязываем конкретный Border.CornerRadius к этому AP. Т. е. стиль будет один, но для каждого контрола свой.

Comment: И да, про ОС проблема актуальна, т.к. в разных ОС WPF использует разные библиотеки стилей.

Comment: А хуже ваше решение тем, что при обновлении AP во время работы программы ваш контрол не отреагирует, ну и плюс, вы добавляете подписчик, но нигде не отписываетесь, что может повлечь утечки памяти, если у вас часто генерируются/удаляются контролы

Comment: @АндрейNOP Так а в том-то и дело, что я не ломаю существующий шаблон по умолчанию, я просто задаю ему значения свойств. Почему это должно вызывать проблемы с ОС?

Comment: Не проблемы с ОС, а увидите другую картину: в шаблоне элемента для другой ОС запросто может не быть этого бордера или он будет расположен где-то глубже в иерархии, например.

Comment: Еще плюс моего подхода — вы увидите как будет выглядеть контрол в дизайнтайме. По сути вопроса написал ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня на Windows 10 для ComboBox сработало следующее:

```
var toggleButton = control.Template.FindName("toggleButton", control) as ToggleButton;
var border = toggleButton.Template.FindName("templateRoot", toggleButton) as Border;
border.CornerRadius = GetCornerRadius(control);
```

т.е. вы просто ошиблись с именем элемента в шаблоне (запутались в стилях?)

Comment: Да-да, как-то так у меня и получилось. Затем немного обрезался контент и дропдаун смотрелся странно, поэтому пришлось дорабатывать, сейчас выложу результат.

Comment: Как думаете, нормальное у меня решение или есть недоработки?

Comment: Кстати по поводу фразы "на Windows 10", разве сами шаблоны по умолчанию не задаются самим WPF (то есть самим .NET Framework), разве они как-то берутся из API ОС? В WPF все контролы вроде же с нуля делались, поэтому по идее должны быть одинаковыми.

Comment: Нет, не из API ОС, но для каждой ОС есть своя тема — библиотека со стилями (Luna/Aero/Aero2/etc), эти библиотеки идут в составе .NET Framework. По умолчанию, приложение выбирает ту тему, которая соответствует ОС, на которой запускается приложение.

Comment: Например, обратите внимание, из какого пространства имен у вас в коде `SystemDropShadowChrome` и из какой сборки он. А теперь посмотрите сборки здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.windows.themes.systemdropshadowchrome(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Понимаю, но я задание `MinWidth` этому контролу не должно как-то радикально менять отображение самого контрола, разве нет?

Comment: А зачем, кстати, задавать MinWidth? Он размер под контент же все равно подстраивает с учетом Padding

Comment: Он так по умолчанию отрисовывается. Если это удалить, то в случае короткого контента `DropDown` будет меньше самой кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Для `ComboBox` надо немноого добавить существующий метод обработки загрузки и добавить различные улучшения для стилей самого выпадающего списка, чтобы у него не было торчащих углов.

```
public static class CornerRadiusSetter
{
    public static CornerRadius GetCornerRadius(DependencyObject obj) => (CornerRadius)obj.GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);

    public static void SetCornerRadius(DependencyObject obj, CornerRadius value) => obj.SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(Border.CornerRadius), typeof(CornerRadius),
            typeof(CornerRadiusSetter), new UIPropertyMetadata(new CornerRadius(), CornerRadiusChangedCallback));

    public static void CornerRadiusChangedCallback(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;

        if (control == null) return;

        control.Loaded -= Control_Loaded;
        control.Loaded += Control_Loaded;
    }

    private static void Control_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;

        if (control == null || control.Template == null) return;

        control.ApplyTemplate();

        CornerRadius cornerRadius = GetCornerRadius(control);

        if (control is ComboBox)
            StyleComboBox(control, cornerRadius);
        else
        {
            // setting borders for non-combobox controls
            Border border = control.Template.FindName("border", control) as Border;

            if (border == null) return;

            border.CornerRadius = cornerRadius;
        }
    }

    private static void StyleComboBox(Control control, CornerRadius cornerRadius)
    {
        Control toggleButton = control.Template.FindName("toggleButton", control) as Control;

        if (toggleButton == null) return;

        toggleButton.ApplyTemplate();

        // Set border radius for border radius border
        Border toggleButtonBorder = toggleButton.Template.FindName("templateRoot", toggleButton) as Border;
        toggleButtonBorder.CornerRadius = cornerRadius;

        // Decrease width of dropdown and center it to avoid showing "sticking" dropdown corners
        Popup popup = control.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", control) as Popup;

        if (popup != null)
            popup.HorizontalOffset = cornerRadius.BottomLeft;

        Decorator shadowChrome = control.Template.FindName("shadow", control) as Decorator;

        if (shadowChrome != null)
        {
            double minWidth = control.ActualWidth - cornerRadius.BottomLeft - cornerRadius.BottomRight;
            if (minWidth > 0)
            {
                shadowChrome.MinWidth = minWidth;
                shadowChrome.Width = minWidth;
            }
        }
    }
}
```